# Using Powershell FileSystemWatcher on iSeries share

Tags: windows, powershell, security, ibm-midrange

I'm using the following powershell script to monitor new files coming
in an IBM iSeries shared folder.

```
# variables
#$folder = "\\10.10.0.120\transform\BE\FORM"
#$folder = "C:\Users\Administrator.ALI\Desktop\AS400"
#$folder = "\\nb091002\Temp"
$folder = "I:\"
$filter = "*.txt"
$aswform = "C:\ASWFORM\aswform.exe"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $folder
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite -bor [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

while($TRUE){
    $result = $watcher.WaitForChanged([System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Changed -bor [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Renamed -bOr [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Created, 2000);
    if($result.TimedOut){
        continue;
    }
    Write-Host $result.Name
    #$aswform $folder

}
```

This seems to work fine on local folders or domain shares.
I've tried mapping the iSeries shared folder to a network drive but it doesn't work.
*(10.10.0.120 is the AS400)*

I'm pretty sure it has to do something with credentials....
Strange thing is I can access the shared folder from within Windows perfectly.

Does anybody have any clues or tips for me?

PS: little detail, I'll be running this script through task sheduler with this trigger

```
powershell -NoExit -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\ASWFORM\watcher.ps1"
```

But first I need it working when running the script manually!

Comment: Ok, I'm curious... what is your purpose for monitoring this?

Comment: Files are being output to this directory for printouts, these files need to be converted to xml. It has to be a transparent process.

Comment: Why write files to that directory instead of one on a Windows server? That ought to help your FileSystemWatcher significantly since the files would be on an actual Windows system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a small C# console application to poll the folder 
instead of using the .Net FileSystemWatcher object.
I manually *(instsrv.exe)* installed this program as a service and it seems to be running ok.
If you want the code, please send me a PM and I'll see to it that you get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to get FileSystemWatcher to work unless the target directory was a Windows NTFS drive.  If I specify the drive letter of the mapped directory I get

```
Exception setting "Path": "The directory name W:\ is invalid."
```

If I use the UNC I get

```
Exception calling "WaitForChanged" with "2" argument(s): "Error reading the \\\\path.to.my.ibm.i\\root\ directory."
```

Against a Novell file server I get the directory name is invalid if I use a drive letter.  If I use a UNC against a Novell drive it does run, but doesn't detect any changes to the file system.  Works fine against a local drive and also against a Windows file server on my network.

Comment: I think our only option is to write our own filesystemwatcher that uses polling for files. For now I'm using software that is able to monitor the iSeries share to read the file, write it locally and then having a watcher look in that folder. The software I'm using is the same that produces the layout. (Bottomline Output Designer/Transform)
So, the problem is not solved but at least I can continue working...